# Differential equation with its variables inside of it

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I don't have any idea on how to approach this equation and couldn't find anything online
this is the equation
$$f(x) = x - \dfrac 12x^2f'(x)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

The given equation is $y=x-\frac{x^2}2\frac{dy}{dx}$. Rearranging it, we get:$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac2{x^2}y=\frac2x$$Can you proceed from here?

Comment: yes, thanks you